# Android String.Format leading zeros issue

Tags: java, string

My string is "1" and i had to add leading zero. I'm using

```
if (mystring.length() == 1) { 
     mystring = String.format("%02d", mystring);
}
```

But I get:

> java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %d can't format
>   java.lang.String arguments

I also already tried with "%02f". Any idea why I'm getting this error ?

Answer (score 2):

Because the %d specifier requires an integer type value to format.  If your string is actually a number, then parse it to a number first, then pass that to the [formatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html):

```
mystring = String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(mystring));
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `String.format("%02d", mystring);` is expecting a decimal number... not a string, the same with %02f which means float

take a look to the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html)